# How to display KDE lock screen time in 24-hour format

Tags: kubuntu, kde, indicator, configuration, lock-screen

Running Kubuntu with the Plasma desktop, 16.04.

I have my desktop configured to 24-hour time, which is what I vastly prefer.

But when the lock screen comes on, it shows me the detested AM/PM format. This cannot stand. Yet after diligent searching, I am unable to find a solution.

Is this configurable in KDE?

Comment: KDE Forums - Wrong time format in plasma5 lock screen: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=130484

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Mr/Ms user26687 above hit upon the correct answer in his/her comment above, but I can't mark a comment as The One True Answer, so I will summarize the content of [the referenced page at kde.org](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=130484).

As a bonus, that page contains instructions for changing the date format to YYYY-DD-MM, just like God, ISO and Gary Houston intended.  Wasn't even asking for that, but got it anyway.  Niii-i-i-i-ice.

HOW TO:

1. Go to the directory

   ```
   /usr/share/plasma/look-and-feel/org.kde.breeze.desktop/contents/components
   ```

Therein you will find a file called `InfoPane.qml` or in 17.04 `Clock.qml`.  Edit it as root.

2. Find this line:

   ```
   text: Qt.formatTime(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"])
   ```

   and change it to

   ```
   text: Qt.formatTime(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"], "hh:mm:ss")
   ```
3. For the ISO date change, find this line:

   ```
   text: Qt.formatDate(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"], Qt.DefaultLocaleLongDate);
   ```

   and change it to

   ```
   text: Qt.formatDate(timeSource.data["Local"]["DateTime"], "yyyy-MM-dd");
   ```
4. Save the changes.
5. That's it!  You don't even need to log out/in, much less restart anything.  Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock your screen and see the change immediately.

Comment: in Kubuntu 17.04 the file name is Clock.qml, rather than InfoPane.qml. Still works like a charm!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, the \**...** is to outline the change, but should NOT be included as part of it. I updated the file exactly as shown, and seemed to break it rather badly. (A locked screen with no place to unlock it.) Had to reboot and remove the asterisks.

Comment: Worked like a charm in Arch. Note I had to change the setting for Breeze theme even though I am using Breeze Dark; I suppose Breeze Dark must source Breeze somewhere along the line.

Comment: Thanks! The only drawback you need to be aware of is that updates can revert the manual changes, as I just had to experience. So it would be better if some permanent, GUI-configurable option were added for this.